# Maximum external symbol length

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I have two questions regarding maximum external symbol length in C++ (global variable, function, class, etc. name):

1. What is the maximum external symbol length in GNU ld and other linkers for C++ language (static linking)?
2. What is the maximum external symbol length for dynamic link libraries on Linux, Windows (dynamic linking)?

Answer (score 3):

This (and many other things) is implementation-defined, as mentioned in the Annex B of the standard. The standar does, however, recommend a minimum limit of 1024 characters, noting that it is only a recommendation:

> Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably
> limited in the size of the programs they can successfully process.
> Every implementation shall document those limitations where known.
>
> <...>
>
> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described
> below or others. The bracketed number following each quantity is
> recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these
> quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance.
>
> <...>
>
> Number of characters in an external identifier [1 024]

Which means that the answer to your question may vary depending on compiler/linker version and target OS.